Find time stamp from which a dataset becomes monotonic
I have a dataframe which contains an altitude column. In the beginning the altitude remains the same in terms of GPS signal fluctuations. At some point the altitude changes, when the GPS receiver is moved during a walk up a mountain.
How would I find the timestamp, when the altitude starts to be continuously moved upwards? A simple 'larger than' comparison would not work as the altitude is jumping a little in the beginning during warm-up.
An example timerow is here:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
df_GPS = pd.DataFrame([['2024-06-21 06:22:38', 605.968389],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:39', 606.009398],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:40', 605.630573],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:41', 605.476367 ],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:42', 605.322161],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:43', 605.268389],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:44', 605.559398],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:45', 606.630573],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:46', 607.476367 ],
                     ['2024-06-21 06:22:47', 609.322161],
                    ], columns=['time', 'Altitude'])


Ideally I would get as result:
time = 2024-06-21 06:22:43
as from there the altitude rises monotonously.
My code is still faulty
start_move = df_GPS.loc[df_GPS['Altitude'] == df_GPS["Altitude"].is_monotonic_increasing, 'time'] 
print(start_move)    

Where is my misspelling?

is_monotonic_increasing applies to the whole Altitude Series not part of it. You could start from the last time and go backwards looking for a difference in Altitude indicating the change.

@user19077881 you mean something like start_move = df_GPS.loc[df_GPS['Altitude'][::-1] == df_GPS["Altitude"].loc[::-1].is_monotonic_decreasing, 'time']  ? This won't work either as obviously I came back down the mountain and the track contains the ascent data, too :-(

I could use a threshold comparing to the previous data. If the difference between two datasets is larger than the threshold It is my start_move time. Obviously that way the track will start a few seconds later...

something like this would be a workaround -even it's not the very intended solution: start_move = df_GPS.loc[df_GPS['Altitude'].diff(periods=1) > 0.5, 'time'].min()

Assuming time has been converted to datatime / timestamp then you could just look backwards from the end to find the change from monotonic. Assuming the time data needs to be sorted then firs reverse the order:
df_GPS_rev = df_GPS.sort_values(by = 'time', ascending = False)

Alternatively if the data is already in time order then as the only requirement is to reverse the existing order, so it is only necessary to reindex:
df_GPS_rev = df_GPS.reindex(index = df_GPS.index[::-1])

then
start_move = df_GPS_rev[df_GPS_rev['Altitude'] < df_GPS_rev['Altitude'].shift(-1)].iloc[0]

print(start_move['time'])

gives:
2024-06-21 06:22:43

If (as later defined in OP comments) the data is NOT always monotonically increasing but for example has decreases at the end, then rolling windows could be checked for being monotonically increasing:
# define window size
win= 3

# find windows which are monotonic increasing
df_GPS['win_inc'] = df_GPS.rolling(win)['Altitude'].apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing)

#get index of end of first increasing window
idx = df_GPS[df_GPS['win_inc'].eq(True)].index[0]

# get time at start of first increasing window
start_move = df_GPS.loc[idx-win+1, 'time']
print(start_move)

which again gives:
2024-06-21 06:22:43

A faster but less concise approach could use Numpy:
# define window size
win= 3
#create numpy array
alt = df_GPS['Altitude'].to_numpy()

#search through np array looking for first increasing window
start_idx = None
for idx, val in enumerate(alt[:1-win]):
    if np.all(np.diff(alt[idx:idx+win]) > 0):
        start_idx = idx
        break

if start_idx is not None:
    start_move = df_GPS.loc[start_idx, 'time']
    print(start_move)
else:
    print('no increasing windows')

which again gives the same result

that might be a way, but manipulating data in terms of sorting it makes me always a headache... there is no option without sorting the dataset first, right?

See edited answer: it is only necessary to reindex rather than sort. Maybe this cures the headache!

well ok, this works for datasets that just climb. The complete dataset contains also data were I came back from the mountain again and here  even reindexing would not work. Hence, I accept the answer as solution as I wasn't aware in the example that I have to add the descent from the mountain, too to completely solve my problem.

See edited answer with rolling window approach which deals with data which also later descends. Hope this is now useful.

wow, cool, that works for a dataset that contains a climb and a descent! I would rate it once more up if I could. Thanks a lot for that help to understand the python programming. The part .apply(lambda x: x.is_monotonic_increasing) was the one I wasn't thinking of...

Although  the code is concise the Pandas rolling approach could be somewhat inefficient for enormous data sets because it finds all increasing windows before using only the first of these. I have a similar albeit less concise approach which follows the same logic using Numpy looping to check only the first increasing window - let me know if this matters to you.

yes, you are right. Larger data sets take a while to go through. If there is a faster solution that terminates the calculation as soon as the first finding occurs I would be curious to learn about it. Do you mean a solution with a for loop?

It does have a for loop but within a Numpy array not Pandas and only to find the first window hence much faster. See edited answer.

seems to be a faster way of calculation. Hence I have somehow to modify one line a little, than it's working on my machine, too: if start_idx is not None:     start_move = df_GPS['time'][start_idx]. Great! Thank you for this nice learning session :-)

the first solution takes about 0.585s, the second about 0.002s processing time for a dataset, that contains 9486 rows of data entries -almost a factor of 300 times faster... That's amazing :-)
